# Integral relating to Fourier transform of tanh

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-transform

I'm trying to find the Fourier transform of $\tanh(x) - \operatorname{sgn}(x)$, and I ended up with the following integral:

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin kx}{e^{2x} + 1} d x$$

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can also use complex integration.
$$I(k)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin kx}{e^{2x} + 1} dx=\frac12\int_0^\infty (1-\tanh x)\sin kx\,dx$$
$$\overset{IBP}{=}-\frac{\cos kx}{2k}(1-\tanh x)\,\bigg|_{x=0}^\infty-\frac1{4k}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ikx}}{\cosh^2x}dx=\frac1{2k}-\frac1{4k}J(k)$$
Integrating along the rectangular contour $C: -R\to R\to R+\pi i\to-R+\pi i\to-R$
$$J(k)\big(1-e^{-\pi k}\big)=\oint_C\frac{e^{ikz}}{\cosh^2z}dz=2\pi i\underset{z=\frac{\pi i}2}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{e^{ikz}}{\cosh^2z}=2\pi k\,e^{-\frac{\pi k}2}$$
$$\Rightarrow\,\, J(k)=\frac{\pi k}{\sinh\frac{\pi k}2}$$
$$\boxed{\,\,I(k)=\frac1{2k}-\frac\pi 4\frac1{\sinh\frac{\pi k}2}\,\,}$$

Comment: (+1) This is how I would have apporached it

Comment: @Mark Viola, thank you :) I wish you all the best in the coming year. So that goodness and reason prevail in 2024.

Comment: And you!  Happy Holidays to you.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to leave a note here regarding the residue calculation. $\frac{e^{ikx}}{\cosh^2 x} = -e^{-\frac{k\pi}{2}} \frac{e^{ik(x-i\frac{\pi}{2})}}{\sinh^2(x-i\frac{\pi}{2})}$

Answer (score 5):

I suggest another approach. For $x>0$ we have
$$
\tanh x 
= \frac{\sinh x}{\cosh x}
= \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x + e^{-x}}
= \frac{1 - e^{-2x}}{1 + e^{-2x}}
= 1 + 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-e^{-2x})^n
= 1 + 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n e^{-2nx}
$$
and $\operatorname{sgn}x=1$ so
$$
\tanh x - \operatorname{sgn}x = 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n e^{-2nx}.
$$
Calculate the one-sided Fourier transform of each term and then sum them. Then do the same for $x<0$ and add that result.

Answer (score 1):

*Another approach.*

$$\int \frac{e ^{ikx}}{e^{2x} + 1}\, d x=-\frac i {k}\,e^{i k x} \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{i k}{2};\frac{2+i k}{2};-e^{2
   x}\right)$$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e ^{ikx}}{e^{2x} + 1}\, d x=\frac{1}{4} \left(H_{-\frac{i k}{4}}-H_{-\frac{i
   k}{4}-\frac{1}{2}}\right)$$
$$\int \frac{\sin(kx)}{e^{2x} + 1}\, d x=\frac{1}{2 k}-\frac{\pi}{4}   \text{csch}\left(\frac{k\pi }{2}\right)$$

Comment: Sorry what are these F and H functions?